# Is it possible to access a listing of products from a virtual catalog from website? (Not its default Catalog) [Virto Commerce]

Tags: e-commerce, virtocommerce

Hello fellow programmers.
I have a situation where I have an e-commerce site where I sell a large variety of items and a specific set of items that I want to have as a virtual catalog. I want this to be a virtual catalog so at the time of shipping, I want to be able to call that virtual catalog and check if any of my cart items are part of the virtual catalog. If so my shipping rates will be different. That is due to the items in the virtual catalog are going to be labelled as a "Dangerous Good" and will need to be shipped via freight.

Hope that is enough information. Just wanting to know how I can call a virtual Catalog from code...

Answer (score 1):

Search is the same for ordinary and virtual catalogs: use [/api/catalog/search/products](https://admin-demo.virtocommerce.com/docs/ui/index#/Catalog%20module/CatalogModuleSearch_SearchProducts) method with "catalogId" and "objectIds".

On the other hand, could you clarify your scenario? Do you really need new virtual catalog, if it’s just for product labeling? A dedicated catalog property for product/category could be enough. Another option to consider: https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-module-catalog-personalization module, enabling to add Tags. One of the tags could be “Dangerous”